# twilio via nodejs to transcribe a call on answer only?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I found an attribute record-on-answer and i am trying to integrate it in my twiml response and it is not working. I am trying to ONLY record when the user answers.
Like my current recording has 5 seconds of "Your call cannot be transferred" that got recorded. Then 5 seconds of silence that got recorded. Then the call when it actually connected which was 26 seconds and properly recorded. I only want the 26 seconds of the third recording. If i call with a regular phone I will never hear the "Your call cannot be transferred".

How would I achieve this?

Here is my code: and then following that are the request bodies. If anyone from twilio can help sort out this coding issue I would be very grateful as I am very frustrated. I have tried recording with dual and mono enabled. *bangs head on keyboard*

```
function callUA(twilNum, uaNum){
console.log('in call ua')
client.calls.create({
    url: 'http://www.REMOVED.com/sendT',
    to: '+1'+uaNum,
    from: '+1'+twilNum,
    method: 'POST',
    status_callback_method: 'POST',
    status_callback: 'https://www.REMOVED.com/tS'
})
}//end callua

app.post('/sendT', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
  var rt = new VoiceResponse();
    rt.record({
    recordingChannels: 'dual',
    recordOnAnswer: true,
    transcribe: true,
    transcribeCallback: 'http://www.autosecurelogin.com/rT'
});
    rt.hangup();
res.status(200);
res.send(rt.toString());



console.log(' finish sendt')
})//end post


app.post('/rT', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
console.log('made to receiveT post');
console.log(req.body);
var ttemp = req['body'].TranscriptionText;
var rightNow = Date.now();
console.log('transcription text ' + ttemp);
var masterFile = __dirname + "/master/transcriptions/"+rightNow+".json";
fs.writeFile(masterFile,  ttemp, function (err) {
})//
res.status(200);
res.send();
console.log('Transcribe Finish');
});



app.post('/tS', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {


console.log('req');
var ttemp = req['body'];
res.status(200);
res.send();
console.log('in call back tS');
});

in call ua
{ Called: 'REMOVED',
  ToState: 'CO',
  CallerCountry: 'US',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  CallerState: 'CO',
  ToZip: '80265',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED',
  CallerZip: '',
  ToCountry: 'US',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  CalledZip: '80265',
  CalledCity: 'DENVER',
  CallStatus: 'in-progress',
  From: 'REMOVED',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  CalledCountry: 'US',
  CallerCity: '',
  Caller: '+17205752321',
  FromCountry: 'US',
  ToCity: 'DENVER',
  FromCity: '',
  CalledState: 'CO',
  FromZip: '',
  FromState: 'CO' }
 finish sendt

in call ua
{ Called: '+REMOVED',
  ToState: 'CO',
  CallerCountry: 'US',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  CallerState: 'CO',
  ToZip: '80265',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED',
  CallerZip: '',
  ToCountry: 'US',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  CalledZip: '80265',
  CalledCity: 'DENVER',
  CallStatus: 'in-progress',
  From: '+REMOVED',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  CalledCountry: 'US',
  CallerCity: '',
  Caller: '+REMOVED',
  FromCountry: 'US',
  ToCity: 'DENVER',
  FromCity: '',
  CalledState: 'CO',
  FromZip: '',
  FromState: 'CO' }
 finish sendt

{ Called: '+REMOVED',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED',
  ToState: 'CO',
  CallerCountry: 'US',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  CallerState: 'CO',
  ToZip: '80265',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED',
  CallerZip: '',
  ToCountry: 'US',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  CalledZip: '80265',
  CalledCity: 'DENVER',
  CallStatus: 'in-progress',
  RecordingSid: 'REMOVED',
  From: '+REMOVED',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  CalledCountry: 'US',
  CallerCity: '',
  Caller: '+REMOVED',
  FromCountry: 'US',
  ToCity: 'DENVER',
  FromCity: '',
  CalledState: 'CO',
  FromZip: '',
  FromState: 'CO',
  RecordingDuration: '31' }
 finish sendt
{ Called: '+REMOVED',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED',
  ToState: 'CO',
  CallerCountry: 'US',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  CallerState: 'CO',
  ToZip: '80265',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED',
  CallerZip: '',
  ToCountry: 'US',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  CalledZip: '80265',
  CalledCity: 'DENVER',
  CallStatus: 'in-progress',
  RecordingSid: 'REMOVED',
  From: '+REMOVED',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  CalledCountry: 'US',
  CallerCity: '',
  Caller: '+REMOVED',
  FromCountry: 'US',
  ToCity: 'DENVER',
  FromCity: '',
  CalledState: 'CO',
  FromZip: '',
  FromState: 'CO',
  RecordingDuration: '5' }
 finish sendt
made to receiveT post
{ ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  TranscriptionType: 'fast',
  TranscriptionUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED/Transcriptions/REMOVED',
  TranscriptionSid: 'REMOVED',
  Called: '+REMOVED',
  RecordingSid: 'REMOVED',
  CallStatus: 'in-progress',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED',
  From: '+REMOVED',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  url: 'http://www.REMOVED.com/rT',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  TranscriptionText: '',
  Caller: '+REMOVED',
  TranscriptionStatus: 'completed',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED' }
transcription text
Transcribe Finish
{ Called: '+REMOVED',
  Digits: 'hangup',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED',
  ToState: 'CO',
  CallerCountry: 'US',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  CallerState: 'CO',
  ToZip: '80265',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED',
  CallerZip: '',
  ToCountry: 'US',
  ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  CalledZip: '80265',
  CalledCity: 'DENVER',
  CallStatus: 'completed',
  RecordingSid: 'REMOVED',
  From: '+REMOVED',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  CalledCountry: 'US',
  CallerCity: '',
  Caller: '+REMOVED',
  FromCountry: 'US',
  ToCity: 'DENVER',
  FromCity: '',
  CalledState: 'CO',
  FromZip: '',
  FromState: 'CO',
  RecordingDuration: '5' }
 finish sendt
made to receiveT post
{ ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  TranscriptionType: 'fast',
  TranscriptionUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED/Transcriptions/REMOVED',
  TranscriptionSid: 'REMOVED',
  Called: '+17202147065',
  RecordingSid: 'REMOVED',
  CallStatus: 'completed',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED',
  From: '+17205752321',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  url: 'http://www.REMOVED.com/rT',
  AccountSid: 'ACcf28aac96af5890681f35809fb0b62eb',
  TranscriptionText: 'Today is Thursday June 27th and the colors of the day are Aqua Baracuda beige and blue confetti the litter Gray Line the melon Onyx are Ange red. And very day thank you.',
  Caller: '+REMOVED',
  TranscriptionStatus: 'completed',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED' }
transcription text Today is Thursday June 27th and the colors of the day are Aqua Baracuda beige and blue confetti the litter Gray Line the melon Onyx are Ange red. And very day thank you.
Transcribe Finish
made to receiveT post
{ ApiVersion: '2010-04-01',
  TranscriptionType: 'fast',
  TranscriptionUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED/Transcriptions/REMOVED',
  TranscriptionSid: 'REMOVED',
  Called: '+REMOVED',
  RecordingSid: 'REMOVED',
  CallStatus: 'completed',
  RecordingUrl: 'https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/REMOVED/Recordings/REMOVED',
  From: '+REMOVED',
  Direction: 'outbound-api',
  url: 'http://www.REMOVED.com/rT',
  AccountSid: 'REMOVED',
  TranscriptionText: 'Your call cannot be transferred please try again later thank you.',
  Caller: '+17205752321',
  TranscriptionStatus: 'completed',
  CallSid: 'REMOVED',
  To: '+REMOVED' }
transcription text Your call cannot be transferred please try again later thank you.
Transcribe Finish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think what you may need is to include an [`action` attribute for your `<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/record#attributes-action). If you don't include a URL in the `action` attribute Twilio will not complete the call when it finishes the recording, it will redirect to the same action again and start trying to record again.

I recommend updating your `/sendT` method to something like this:

```
app.post('/sendT', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  var rt = new VoiceResponse();
  rt.record({
    recordingChannels: 'dual',
    recordOnAnswer: true,
    transcribe: true,
    transcribeCallback: 'http://www.REMOVED.com/rT',
    action: 'http://www.REMOVED.com/recorded'
  });
  res.status(200);
  res.send(rt.toString());
  console.log(' finish sendt')
})//end post
```

And then add one more `/recorded` endpoint that replies with a [`<Hangup>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/hangup)

```
app.post('/recorded', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {
  var rt = new VoiceResponse();
  rt.hangup();
  res.status(200);
  res.send(rt.toString());
});
```

That should stop you getting extra transcribed messages through.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out and forgot to delete the question, you actually answered this question before, and I referred back to my original answer by you. hahaha. It is in the documentation though just a foot note